# Create a SequenceNumber using a combination of values

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create the final column "SeqNumber". My source data is in SQL Server

I used the following

```
((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by FileDate ORDER BY AutoNumberKey)-1)/(CalcSeqNumber)+1) SeqNumber
```

It does the CalcSeqNumber = 5 properly by grouping values 070, 071, 300, 301 and 306 together but CalcSeqNumber = 3 is incorrect. I am expecting it to restart the SeqNumber anytime it sees a new 300 value *within* the 3 sequence or a new 5 sequence (defined by 070 as the start of a 5 sequence)

| FileDate | RTI | AutoNumberKey | CalcSeqNumber | SeqNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20211004 | 070 | 55644 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 071 | 55645 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55646 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55647 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55648 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55649 | 3 | 2 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55650 | 3 | 2 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55651 | 3 | 2 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55652 | 3 | 3 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55653 | 3 | 3 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55654 | 3 | 3 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55655 | 3 | 4 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55656 | 3 | 4 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55657 | 3 | 4 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55658 | 3 | 5 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55659 | 3 | 5 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55660 | 3 | 5 |

```
Table scripts for creation and sample data
    CREATE TABLE [dbo].[SeqDataCheck](
        [FileDate] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [RTI] [varchar](50) NULL,
        [AutoNumberKey] [int] NULL,
        [CalcSeqNumber] [int] NULL  
     ) ON [PRIMARY]
     GO


INSERT INTO [dbo].[SeqDataCheck]
           ([FileDate]
           ,[RTI]
           ,[AutoNumberKey]
           ,[CalcSeqNumber])       
     VALUES
           ('20211004','070',55644,5),
           ('20211004','071',55645,5),
           ('20211004','300',55646,5),
           ('20211004','301',55647,5),
           ('20211004','306',55648,5),
           ('20211004','300',55649,5),
           ('20211004','301',55650,5),
           ('20211004','306',55651,5),
           ('20211004','300',55652,5),
           ('20211004','301',55653,5),
           ('20211004','306',55654,5),
           ('20211004','300',55655,5),
           ('20211004','301',55656,5),
           ('20211004','306',55657,5),
           ('20211004','300',55658,5),
           ('20211004','301',55659,5),
           ('20211004','306',55660,5)

GO
```

Comment: If you provide your sample data as DDL+DML you make it much easier to assist.

Comment: _ I am expecting it to restart the SeqNumber anytime it sees a new 300 value within the 3 sequence or a new 5 sequence_ I am unclear what a "new" 300 value within a sequence is. But if you need ROW_NUMBER to number each value CalcSeqNumber seperately, then it should be part of the PARTITION BY clause, `PARTITION BY FileDate, CalcSeqNumber)`.

Comment: I should have been more clearer. What I meant is that SeqNumber should say 1 for the first five records (since they have 5 next to it), then 2 for the next 3 (sequence of 3 -- 300, 301, 306), then 3 for the next 3 and so on.

Comment: Small nitpick, but your `INSERT` script for the sample data doesn't match your sample data table

Answer (score 0):

Adding another `PARTITION BY` predicate to also partition by `CalcSeqNumber` should get you the desired outcome.

In effect, this means that you want the row number to start at 1 for each combined unique combination of FileDate and CalcSeqNumber. That number will increment for each time that combination is repeated.

```
SELECT FileDate,
       RTI,
       AutoNumberKey,
       CalcSeqNumber,
       ((ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by FileDate, CalcSeqNumber ORDER BY AutoNumberKey)-1)/(CalcSeqNumber)+1) AS SeqNumber
  FROM SeqDataCheck;
```

Results:

| FileDate | RTI | AutoNumberKey | CalcSeqNumber | SeqNumber |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55649 | 3 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55650 | 3 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55651 | 3 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55652 | 3 | 2 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55653 | 3 | 2 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55654 | 3 | 2 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55655 | 3 | 3 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55656 | 3 | 3 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55657 | 3 | 3 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55658 | 3 | 4 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55659 | 3 | 4 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55660 | 3 | 4 |
| 20211004 | 070 | 55644 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 071 | 55645 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 300 | 55646 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 301 | 55647 | 5 | 1 |
| 20211004 | 306 | 55648 | 5 | 1 |